# Mail content of Google Docs using Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am trying to mail the content of gdocs(not as attachment) using GAS, and I tried to export the file into HTML and then mail the same. May I know is there any other work around.

```
function test_mail_() {
 var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
 var url = 
 "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + id + "&exportFormat=html";
 var param = {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
 };
 var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
 var raw = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe("Subject: Test\r\n" +
           "From: " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + "\r\n" +
           "To: test@gmail.com\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
            html + "\r\n\r\n");
 var message = Gmail.newMessage();
 message.raw = raw;
 var sentMsg = Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, 'test@gmail.com'); 
}
```

[I need something like this without padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os821.png)

[But what I get is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vebiw.png)

Moreover the drawings that I have inserted in the document are not displayed in the mail content.

Comment: What's the problem?  You tried to export the file contents.  What happened?  Did the contents get exported but not the way that you wanted?  I see that you are getting the active document.  So, is this code bound to a Google Doc?

Comment: When i mail the content i cant get the inserted drawing exported. Also there is padding which makes the content of the document look bad. I have edited the question with the attachment @SandyGood

Comment: The code will need to edit the HTML, and delete/add/change some inline CSS settings.  Search the HTML for padding, margin and border settings.

Comment: yeah. got it done. am eager in knowing is there any other way to get the content rather than converting it to html as i cant get the drawings being exported, and also if there any way to embed html in google document @SandyGood

Comment: If there is no header and/or footer you could try [getBody - Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBody())  You could try `DriveApp.getFileById(id).getAs('application/pdf').getDataAsString();`  or `DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString('utf8')`